# Remove the period from an ordered list that has specific values to the list number - css

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have an ordered list with specific values to the "list number".

I have seen solutions for a list that increments the value, however my values need to be specific and cannot change.

HTML

```
<td class="list">
  <ol class="junkfood">
    <li value="2">Cookies®</li>
    <li value="1">Chocolate</li>
    <li value="2">Brownies</li>
    <li value="10">Ice cream sandwich</li>
  </ol>
</td>
```

Right now it prints out as

```
2. Cookies
1. Chocolate
2. Brownies
10. Ice cream sandwich
```

I need the numbers to print out as 'values'

```
2 Cookies
1 Chocolate
2 Brownies
10 Ice cream sandwich
```

Comment: I'm confused by this. How can there be two #2 items in an ordered list, unless they were tied for something? Why is the ordered list... *not* ordered? The period has a specific meaning and you can't just remove it. I'm not sure this was meant to be an ordered list at all, and the numbers don't mean what I think they mean. Something tells me this should be marked up entirely differently and not with an ol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is perfectly possible with CSS if you use data attributes:

```css
ol {
    list-style:none;
}
li:before {
    content:attr(data-value) ' ';
}
```

```html
<ol class="junkfood">
    <li data-value="2">Cookies®</li>
    <li data-value="1">Chocolate</li>
    <li data-value="2">Brownies</li>
    <li data-value="10">Ice cream sandwich</li>
</ol>
```

It is however also a rather weird use of HTML this way, as you're using an *ordered* list to represent *unordered* data. Therefore you should replace `<ol>` with `<ul>` in my sample to be semantically correct. The same CSS applies just fine this way, that's just presentational.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want an ordered list then, you want an unordered list (ul)

```
<ul>
    <li value="2">2 Cookies®</li>
    <li value="1">1 Chocolate</li>
    <li value="2">2 Brownies</li>
    <li value="10">10 Ice cream sandwich</li>
</ul>
```

I included the value in the list item itself as your example shows.

2 Cookies
1 Chocolate
2 Brownies
10 Ice cream sandwich

HTH,
Eric